# Prove $\ (b-1)e^{-b} < (a-1)e^{-a} $ for every $\ 2 < a < b $

Tags: calculus

Prove: for every $\ 2 < a < b $ : $\ (b-1)e^{-b} < (a-1)e^{-a} $

My first try was to try and build a function and show it is going down:

$\ f(x) = (b-1)e^{-b} - (a-1)e^{-a} $

but I don't know how to handle such function. Is there any easier way?

Comment: Where is the variable $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take 
$$f(x) = (x-1)e^{-x}$$
then 
$$f'(x) = e^{-x}-e^{-x}(x-1)=e^{-x}(2-x)<0$$
when $x>2$ and so $f$ is decreasing when $x>2.$ Thus for $2<a<b$ we have that 
$$f(a)>f(b)\implies  (b-1)e^{-b} < (a-1)e^{-a}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/Guide**

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{x-1}{e^x}.
$$
By computing its derivative, show that $f$  is decreasing for $x>2$ from which the claim will follow.